# Modeling nested configuration for custom Gradle task

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm developing a custom Gradle task in Java (`public class MyCustomTask extends DefaultTask`) and I'm targeting Gradle 5.3. I like to write something like that in my `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.register("myTask", MyCustomTask) {
    languages {
        de {
            include "images/de", "assets/de"
            languageFile "de.properties"
        }
        en {
            include "images/en", "assets/en"
            languageFile "en.properties"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I have to declare the configuration properties in my custom task to be able to have a dynamic list of languages (e.g. `it`, `fr` and `es` would be possible instead of `en` and `de`)? It should be possible to have multiple instances of the task, too.

Comment: You probably want to use this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:container(java.lang.Class). See http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/02/gradle-goodness-create-objects-with-dsl.html for an example

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for pointing out `NamedDomainObjectContainer`. It's almost what I need. Problem: If I have multiple instances of `MyCustomTask`, all `NamedDomainObjectContainer` instances are merged together and I'm unable to separate them afterwards. I updated my code sample to indicate that I'm looking for task configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by "instances are merged together"? Could you add an example of your code?